# Trying SQL table update matching on string field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008r2-express

Could really use some help with an update query...(SQL Serer 2008 R2 Express)
I have two tables, `tblJP` and `tblMaster`.

I only have a string field that matches between the two tables.

```
tblJP AND tblMaster
```

I need to update `tblJP.LangString` with `tblMaster.Long_text` when

```
tblJP.short_text = tblMaster.short_text AND tblMaster.Lang = 'jp'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am spinning my wheels trying all sorts of logic and syntax from creating temp tables to other types of joins all with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple update with an `INNER JOIN` should do the trick.

```
UPDATE     tblJP
SET        tblJP.LangString = tblMaster.Long_Text
FROM       tblJP
INNER JOIN tblMaster ON tblMaster.alt_text = tblJP.short_text
WHERE      tblMaster.Lang = 'jp'
```

**WARNING:** Never run an update statement against your production server without first testing it against a development server - especially when someone else wrote the SQL.

Comment: +1 For the disclaimer! This can cause indeterminate results if there is more than one matching row from the join (an issue avoided with `merge`)

Comment: Also, regarding James' warning: I like to start any update statement with a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and close with `--     COMMIT`. Then I can check the number of rows affected and select and F5 to commit if it is what I expect. (Although this doesn't verify the data change...)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `MERGE`

```
MERGE INTO tblJP
USING (SELECT *
       FROM   tblMaster
       WHERE  Lang = 'jp') AS SOURCE
ON SOURCE.alt_text = tblJP.short_text
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET LangString = SOURCE.Long_Text;
```

In the event that the `JOIN` returns multiple rows you will be alerted to the problem with an error `The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once.`

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I saw your comment, but I've never used `MERGE` before so I wasn't sure how to incorporate that into my answer.